# How are .pyd files made from C++ projects?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, ms-media-foundation, pyd

My current goal is to get this repo, [CV-camera-finder](https://github.com/pvys/CV-camera-finder), to be compatible with Python 3.10. In the README file, the original publisher says

> A simple function to find a connected camera list with media foundation. This is just a modified code of a sample found in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureToFile to use in python.

> Download pymf.pyd(32-bit -> file in folder 32, 64-bit -> ...) to your PYTHONPATH to just use it. If you want to modify it, edit cpp files and rebuild it.

My knowledge of Python is intermediate and C++ beginner at best. I downloaded Visual Studio 2022 and attempted to rebuild it myself with no success. I used his cap.cpp and pymf.cpp files, as well as the capture.h files from the referenced Media Foundation samples as I was under the impression based off of includes that I didn't need anything else. I pointed my include of Python.h to the one located in the 3.10 include folders assuming that would fix the problem.

I ran into multiple issues. The first being

```
unable to open 'python310.lib'
```

I added an additional library dependency pointing to the 3.10 libs folder. After doing that, here are the errors I am getting now.

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol main
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

I am clearly over my head with this but I would really like to get this working for Python 3.10. Could anyone provide an steps/advice/tutorials/etc on getting this built and made into a .pyd?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work? I'd like to use CV-Camera-Finder too, but it's reliance on Python 3.7 breaks it for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change your project settings in Visual Studio following this link [writing python extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). Specifically the `Additional Include Directories` and `Additional Library Directories` under linker. Also, look at the `target file extension` is `pyd` and `dll` for configuration type.

If you have that, along with the `capture.h` from the MF github you have, it should work. Also, I added the following lines to my `capture.h` else VS wouldnt find some of the libraries.

```
#pragma once
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <Dbt.h>
```

Tested with python3.8 and windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> LNK2001 unresolved external symbol main

The program lacks an entry function. If you don't want to use main, please specify the configuration type of the project as lib or dll.